# What does this constant in the parameter do?

Tags: jquery

It's a cross fade slide show. I don't understand what this does in the code below: `rotatePics(1);`

HTML

```
<div id="photos">
  <img alt="Glendatronix" src="../../images/glenda_200.jpg" />
  <img alt="Darth Fader" src="../../images/fader_200.jpg" />
  <img alt="Beau Dandy" src="../../images/beau_200.jpg" />
  <img alt="Johnny Stardust" src="../../images/johnny_200.jpg" />
  <img alt="Mo' Fat" src="../../images/mofat_200.jpg" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  rotatePics(1);
}

function rotatePics(currentPhoto) {
  var numberOfPhotos = $('#photos img').length;
  currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos;
  $('#photos img').eq(currentPhoto).fadeOut(function() {
     // re-order the z-index
     $('#photos img').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css(
          'zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + currentPhoto) % numberOfPhotos
        );
     });
     $(this).show();
    setTimeout(function() {rotatePics(++currentPhoto);}, 4000);
  });
}
```

Comment: What constant parameter?

Comment: Two upvotes for a question that's barely readable and very basic?

Answer (score 1):

"1" is just the starting position.

`rotatePics(++currentPhoto)`; <-- this increments the position and calls itself.

Comment: oh im a fool it may happend when you read the book on 4:00 am thanx anyway:D thanx alot thread closed

Comment: one another question can u explain me how this is setting the z-index?

Comment: z-index allows overlapping of elements. The one with the higher z-index will be on top, usually (lower version of IE have bugs regarding this).

Answer (score 0):

`rotatePics(1);` -> is just a starter. It just says that it should start with image 1.

The rotate logic is this `setTimeout(function() {rotatePics(++currentPhoto);}, 4000);` which rotates every 4 seconds.

```
 setTimeout(function() {          //-> set Timer
      rotatePics(++currentPhoto); //-> recursion call
 }, 4000);                        //-> 4 seconds wait time
```